# Change the Background image in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage, uinavigationbar, frame

I want to change my background image in Navigation Bar.in my code below

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;

UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2_ram.jpg"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image1.image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

image is changed but height of the image is not changed why?

Comment: What do you mean by height of the image?

Answer (score 2):

You should not set like that , if you are considering iOS 4.0 also

use this

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgTopBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

or for iOS 5

use this, no need to give frame to it, and you cant change the height more than 44, the default height of navigation bar is **44**

```
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgTopBar.png"];
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```